# optimization problem with L2-norm constraint

Tags: constrained-optimization, convex-optimization

I am currently trying to solve a regression problem, which leads me to an optimization problem. Say that we have measured data ($\hat{S}(\omega)\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$), and each entry of this matrix is a $d$-sized vector containing frequency-dependent measurements. We can perform the regression by minimizing

\begin{equation}
\min_A ||S - \hat{S}||_2^2, \quad
\end{equation}

where $ S\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, and $S_{ij} = MA_{ij}$, where $M\in\mathbb{C}^{d\times k}$, and $A_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}^{k} \ \forall (i,j) \in (1,2, ...,N) \times (1,2,...,N)$. Note that each entry of the model has its respective vector of coefficients $A_{ij}$ that soughts to model the respective $\hat{S}_{ij}$. This is a fairly simple problem so far, just take the derivative of the objective function w.r.t. A and set it to zero. However, the complication arises when the constraint

\begin{equation}
 || S||_2^2 \leq 1
\end{equation}
must be met. I'm clueless as to how to implement this constraint in this problem. Per my understanding, this is a convex optimization problem owed to the L2-norm squared nature of the objective function. However, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed given the aforementioned constraint.

Comment: It seems to be a non-linearly constrained optimization problem. Perhaps you could take a look at https://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/leyffer/images/7/75/NLP-Solvers.pdf for a list of solvers.

Comment: He's asking for implementation help, not a list of solvers to use seems to me.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the issue? Is the issue optimization with inequalities?

Comment: This is what is called a quadratically-constrained quadratic program (QCQP). You might find literature by searching for this term.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program

Comment: @EMP I'm still thinking about the "issue" itself. It appears that I may need to do some reformulation on the problem before I can tackle it. As is, it seems that there are some issues dealing with the matrices dimensions. I wanted to see if somebody else has encountered a somewhat similar problem, and what literature may be available.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you. I'll update the question if I find something worth the update.